# Grass v.clean.snap with Polygons

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, topology

I am doing some topology testing using Grass in QGIS.  I am hoping to snap nodes to eliminate gaps between polygons.  When I use the v.clean.snap function in Grass it does not work on polygons. When I test it on lines it completes the tasks as I was hoping.  Does anyone know of a way to run v.clean.snap or a similar function in Grass on Polygons?  Attached are two screen grabs showing the errors as polygons, and the fix as a line.[image: Grass v.clean.snap with polygons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mhm, not sure. from the grass manual for v.clean ... `snap: snap lines to vertex in threshold`
It says lines, not boundaries. Don't know how semantically over-correct those manuals are, but a boundary of a polygon isn't a line i think.

Did you try using the snapping while importing the layer to grass? Thats what i tend to do (advanced options of v.in.ogr).

an the manual there says:

```
snap=float
Snapping threshold for boundaries
'-1' for no snap
```